# Numpy matrix for a 3D Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matplotlib

I'm using the following `matplotlib` code to generate a 3D graph:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlim(-50, 50)
ax.set_ylim(-50, 50)
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

plt.show()
```

The problem is that I would like to have control over the Matrix to display in the graph.

I've been trying with the numpy matrix generation,

```
X = np.matrix([[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]])
```

but is been giving me an error of:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

Does anyone know what to do?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. To know the format in which you should enter the data for X, Y and Z, do the following.

After line `X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)` add this line `print X`

You will know the input format. For your problem, modify the following

```
X = np.matrix([[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]])
```

to 
`X = [[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]]`

Accordingly change Y and Z also.

```
X = [[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]]
Y = [[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]]
Z = [[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]]
```

Comment: Hello Rajesh... I already tried the print and inputing the matrix as you say, but the code is giving me another error. `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`. Let me know what you think about this. Thank you...

Comment: Hi James, Did you try removing np.matrix ?

Comment: Yeah I did, I removed `X = np.matrix([[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]])` and added `X = [[-30., -10., 10.],[ -30., -10., 10.],[-30., -10., 10.]]`, Thx.

Comment: As edited, you have to do the same for Y and Z. It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Rajesh I found the problem... I forgot to change also Y and Z. Thank you very much!! Cheers!